# Using AppleScript to Send Email from Mail.app to Multiple Addresses

Tags: mail.app, email, applescript

I am able to successfully send out an email with an attachment to a single email address using the code below:

```
on run argv
    set theSubject to (item 1 of argv)
    set theAttachmentFile to (item 2 of argv)

    tell application "Mail"

        set theAddress to "recipient1@domain.com" -- the receiver 
        set theSignatureName to "Sig" -- the signature name 

        set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, visible:true}

        tell msg to make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}
        tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}

        set message signature of msg to signature theSignatureName

        send msg
    end tell
end run
```

However, I can't figure out how to change this code to send the email to both recipient1@domain.com and recipient2@domain.com. Does anyone know how I would go about doing so? I'm very new to AppleScript, so I'd greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to tweak the `set theAddress` line and the `tell msg to make new to recipient` line to make the following code run as intended:

```
on run argv
    set theSubject to (item 1 of argv)
    set theAttachmentFile to (item 2 of argv)

    tell application "Mail"

        set theAddress to {"recipient1@domain.com","recipient2@domain.com"} 
        set theSignatureName to "Sig" -- the signature name 

        set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, visible:true}

        tell msg
            repeat with i from 1 to count theAddress
                make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:item i of theAddress}
            end repeat
        end tell
        tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}

        set message signature of msg to signature theSignatureName

        send msg
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Do you think that it is possible to set the list of email addresses from a txt file?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's possible assuming 1 email address per line:

```
set srcFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "myFile.txt"


set theAddresses to paragraphs of (read file srcFile as «class utf8»)


repeat with theAddress in theAddresses
 # ... insert code to create and send email to each recipient "theAddress" is each email address
end repeat
```